Is it possible to intialize state variable using useSearchParams in NextJS?
I am trying to initialize a state variable by assigning it the value of query/search parameter.
For example, if the full URL is http://localhost:3000/mycomponent?author=John
Then I would like to assign the value John to my state variable named author, like this:
const [author, setAuthor] = useState(useSearchParams().get("author") || "abc")
But abc gets assigned to the state variable author, instead of John.
I guess useSearchParams() is not meant to be used where I am trying to use it.
Below is the full code:
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

function MyComponent() {

    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState(useSearchParams().get("author") || "abc");

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Search Results for: {author}</h1>
        </div>
    );

}

export default MyComponent;

I can assign the correct value to author in useEffect hook but useEffect runs after a slight delay, and because of that delay, the header initially shows up as Search Results for:
Then it changes to Search Results for: John.
The delay isn't significant but noticeable.

You probably don't need to be making useSearchParams into a state variable at all.  State variables let you do things when React re-renders the component (after a state variable changes) ... but useSearchParams will already re-render your component when it changes.
If you really did need to remember a previous search param and you need to re-render when it changes (again, unlikely), you could use a useEffect to set the state variable ... but this almost certainly not what you want:
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const [author, setAuthor] = 
    useState(searchParams.get("author") || "abc");
useEffect(() =>{
    setAuthor(searchParams);
}, [searchParams]);

What you probably want is just a regular old JS variable:
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const author = useSearchParams().get("author");

This will work just fine because author gets updated every time the component re-renders (ie. whenever searchParams or a state variable changes).  This means it will always be equal to the author, without any need for state variables.

Thank yo for taking out the time to respond. What you suggested is something that I have tried already. The problem is that searchParams.get("author") never returns the correct value of query parameter in the URL. The default value "abc" always gets assigned to const author.
searchParams or useSearchParams() only seem to work when I use it inside the useEffect hook. The problem with useEffect is that the there is a slight delay which is noticeable and I am trying to figure out a way to make that delay as minimal as possible.

In general, as per https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params, useSearchParams return the parameters of the current URL ... which means that (assuming you are on a page with that parameter) your call of that hook should not result in null.  However, depending on what you are doing (eg. static rendering, calling the hook from layout, etc.) you might need to do more: see that link for more info.

In general in React though, if you have a "page flashes wrong UI, then updates and displays the correct UI", the solution is to return null from your component until the data you want (in this case the search params) is ready.  Again, see the docs for a proper solution, but as a quick fix you might just want to do if (!searchParams.get("author") ) return null;.  That way when the page first loads the user will see nothing, then the search params will come back, you'll re-render, and the user will see the (working) page, for the first time.
